# php bootstrap gallery on singlepage

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, gallery, singlepage

How can I do on single page app some gallery with auto-load image from folder? I'm now using bootstrap for the gallery , but I have like 800 mb of pictures and I would like to load theme from folder with some script.Next I would like to make something like album I've done it on casual page like I had a little thumb picture after click it href to site with the picture in album, but in single page site there is only one page. How can I dynamically change the content from little thumb pictures to album content.

Comment: Google "pagination". Because 800, oufff... on a single page? That's be like 40-80 screen fulls to scroll through, unless you've got something else in mind.

Comment: wow , that's seems to be a good solution for albums maybe , without this thumb pictures :) LOL there is sorry a typo 800 mb of pictures :D

Comment: There are jQuery/PHP libraries out there that will do the work "for you". Complete with auto-detecting the given files in a folder with "Prev/Next" links.

Comment: But how could I do something like I've loaded gallery1 for example on one block of page after click on button I would like to load gallery2 on the same block

Comment: You'll need to research this. Your question is much too broad. I've seen them before, back when I used to be heavily into photo galleries. You just need to use the right keywords to minimize your time on Google.